# Change from UEFI to BIOS: can not install grub

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I wanted to change from UEFI to BIOS on my Samsung Series 9 Laptop to be able to use features such as keyboard backlight. I lossley followed this instruction [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360543/convert-from-efi-to-bios-boot)

But when I restarted there was no boot loader.
Then I started a boot stick un CM mode and tried to install grub manually and with boot repair. with no success. boot repair keeps purching and never ends. manual install shows no error reported but there is still no bootloader :(

Can someone help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be mentioned in the answers, you need the correct GRUB package. For BIOS this is at least `grub-pc-bin`. On a GPT partition you also need a BIOS boot partition, I wrote about how to set this up in: [Is it still possible to install Ubuntu to an external harddrive with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581)