# Ubuntu Server dual boot prevents booting to windows

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, windows

I wanted to install an ubuntu server as a dual boot option along side my windows system. During install I created a partition to install the server and I am certain this worked just fine. The problem that I am running into is that the server install dwon't allow me to boot to windows. When I change the boot sequence it changes it back.

I have been trying to find a solution to fix my windows bootloader and delete the ubuntu server but have not been able to make a lot of progres.

How would I achieve this from the server commando line?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I could not boot to my Windows is because on installment ubuntu, which should have been installed on a separate partition, had wiped my disk clean.

Certainly not my first time installing a dual-boot system, but this has never happened to me. If my memory serves me right, the partition that I had created was already merged back to the rest of the drive prior to getting the option where to install.

I am not certain what exactly caused this and I am not feeling like trying to find out what I did wrong. Assuming it is my fault, as I reckon the installation only does what I tell it to.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote this answer if you posted it is an answer to [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/) because it doesn't say how to fix it even though it's interesting to know that. If you copy/pasted [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086535#1086535) as an answer to [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/) instead, I would upvote it though.

Comment: I agree with @karel: post an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/217904/) and then leave 2 comments at each one of us and we'll go and upvote there and use your question here as a signpost to the answer over there!  **;-)**  *Kom op, kerel!*