# Not able to boot into Windows after error in installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

I have tried to install Ubuntu with my windows 1o. But while installing I got message that some `fatal error has occurred`. And after that when i restarted my laptop it's showing no `Boot Device Not Found` for my HP device. What should i do ? Also I don't want to loose my hard-disk data.

After running Boot repair from ubuntu loaded using usb I got this message

```
LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?
```

Comment: You have an Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 dual boot , and you can't boot into Windows 10. Can you boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: @karel No there is no option to boot into any of them. It directly showing the screen that no boot device and Ubuntu was not installed previously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1203888/

Comment: Thanks @karel, your first post's some part worked for me. I'll answer how i solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After reading many posts I was able to solve this problem with basic boot-repair tool of Ubuntu.

**Using a Ubuntu Live DVD and Boot Repair**

1. Boot from a Ubuntu Live DVD or USB
2. Type these lines in the terminal one line at a time.

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install boot-repair
> ```

3. Search for Boot-Repair in the Dash and launch it.

[image]

To fix your computer with Boot-repair, simply click the "Recommended Repair" button. Then follow the steps. It will fix all the problems and then After you will be booted to ubuntu and then run following command to fix the grub menu

```
sudo update-grub
```

It worked for me.