# LegacyWindows detected, Grub is unable to detect Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Windows does not appear in grub menu, what do I do?

I tried Boot Repair and I got:
`LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB)`

I did

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  53.5MB  52.4MB  primary   ntfs
 2      53.5MB  268GB   268GB   primary   ntfs
 3      268GB   471GB   202GB   extended
 5      268GB   468GB   200GB   logical   ext4
 6      468GB   470GB   2047MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 7      470GB   471GB   98.6MB  logical   fat32           boot, esp
```

Windows was in the grub menu once but when I tried to run it said:
`Invalid EFI file path` then it got removed from the grub menu

I am using last version of ubuntu and gnu grub 2.06

When I installed Ubuntu I choose the options:
`Something else`
and I didn't delete any partitions I used free space

this is what I see in the file explorer:
[image: file explorer after clicking the windows volume]

This what I get when I try staring my pc on CSM boot like it was before installing ubuntu

```
Intel(R) Boot Agent CL v0.1.06 Copyright (C) 1997-2013, Intel Corporation

PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel Boot Agent. Insert system disk in drive.

Press any key when ready....

Please check if the Boot Mode is correct in the BIOS settings.

The BIOS settings menu is launched by pressing the [F2] key after you reboot.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360543/convert-from-efi-to-bios-boot-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Windows usually boots in UEFI mode but if you have an old installation that has been gradually upgraded to Windows 10 it can boot in the original legacy mode. Judging by the position of your EFI partition you have just installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode. They are not compatible. You need to get both booting in the same mode so if the Ubuntu install is very new probably easiest to reinstall Ubuntu in legacy mode.

Comment: From what I understand I have 3 boot modes
CSM,UEFI and UEFI (legacy) but when I installed it my pc was in CSM boot so Can you tell how to fix it

Comment: The link provided by @karel gives you a solution that will get both OS booting in the same mode https://askubuntu.com/questions/360543/convert-from-efi-to-bios-boot-mode  One downside of CSM is that the largest disk you can address with it is 2TB. If that’s an issue for you you might want to consider reinstalling everything in UEFI mode

Comment: *I have 3 boot modes CSM,UEFI and UEFI (legacy)* Nope. CSM=Legacy. There are only two modes: UEFI, the one that should be used for any modern OS in modern hardware (post-2012), and Legacy which emulates the old BIOS and should be used only for OSes that don't support UEFI mode (there's no current and supported OS that doesn't support UEFI mode).

Comment: What I don't understand is that my pc is not booting at legecy mode and I am scared if I convert Ubuntu I will fail

Comment: It’s not booting windows in legacy mode using grub because it looks like you have grub installed for UEFI. Hence it doesn’t see legacy Windows. If you follow the advice in @karel link (the accepted answer) you should be ok. You don’t have encryption to deal with so it should be easier. If it doesn’t work ask another question giving the best description you can of any error messages etc…

Comment: Ok I'll try that (the answer seems quite hard to do cause I don't know what to use for example it says delete partition and I don't know if I should do it with terminal or something)

Comment: You can delete a partition in the terminal but it’s much easier to do it with the GParted app. You should have that in your new Ubuntu or in the installation media. Just choose “Try Ubuntu” and not install Ubuntu to get into a live environment that behaves just like normal Ubuntu. Just ensure you apply the change before exiting the app