# Unable to use Windows 10 from GRUB menu and other problems in Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a Windows booting issue while using Ubuntu along with Windows 10.

Ubuntu works normally. Windows seems to be booting with a partition error.

Windows 10 only works after going to boot menu (F12), but from GRUB menu Windows 10 shows an error.

errors:

```
(i)cant find command 'drivemap'
(ii)invalid efi file path
```

boot-repair summary:

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on sdb5
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sda1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic root=UUID=f1501797-4928-43d3-a4d5-e8c71a54e4e0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sdb5      ext4  9.1G  6.7G  1.9G  78% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F2(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0004,0001,0002
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(3,MBR,0x0,0x4a82000,0x106000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.T.S.S.T.c.o.r.p. .C.D.D.V.D.W. .S.H.-.2.2.4.F.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.S.U.9.Y.6.G.A.0.3.9.0.K.5. . . . . . ......AMBO
Boot0002* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.K.I.N.G.S.T.O.N. .S.V.3.0.0.S.3.7.A.2.4.0.G....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.5.2.0.B.6.8.7.1.5.5.0.C.7.6.8. . . . ......AMBOAMNO........o.1.2.8.G.B. .S.S.D....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.A.A.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.5.9.8.9. . . . ......AMBO
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(3,MBR,0x0,0x4a82000,0x106000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot0004* UEFI OS   HD(3,MBR,0x0,0x4a82000,0x106000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI)


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda1    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb5    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb6    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb5    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb6    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xd462d556
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *      1026048 463433159 462407112 220.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2       463433728 464488447   1054720   515M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
sda3       464490496 468856831   4366336   2.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk sdb: 119.24 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xf4acedc8
      Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1           2048 58593279 58591232 27.9G 83 Linux
sdb2       58595326 79200255 20604930  9.8G  5 Extended
sdb5       58595328 78125055 19529728  9.3G 83 Linux
sdb6  *    78127104 79200255  1073152  524M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:240GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA KINGSTON SV300S3:;
1:525MB:237GB:237GB:ntfs::boot;
2:237GB:238GB:540MB:ntfs::msftres;
3:238GB:240GB:2236MB:ntfs::;
sdb:128GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA 128GB SSD:;
1:1049kB:30.0GB:30.0GB:ext4::;
2:30.0GB:40.6GB:10.5GB:::;
5:30.0GB:40.0GB:9999MB:ext4::;
6:40.0GB:40.6GB:549MB:fat32::boot, esp;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 0.03MiB:501MiB:501MiB
sdb: 38672MiB:122104MiB:83432MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                  
├─sda1 ntfs     E0661E18661DF050                     d462d556-01                                     
├─sda2 ntfs     8A649F84649F71A5                     d462d556-02                                     
└─sda3 ntfs     90885B02885AE66E                     d462d556-03                          New Volume 
sdb                                                                                                  
├─sdb1 ext4     a28c5665-adcb-4999-830e-34a72252755e f4acedc8-01                                     
├─sdb2                                               f4acedc8-02                                     
├─sdb5 ext4     f1501797-4928-43d3-a4d5-e8c71a54e4e0 f4acedc8-05                                     
└─sdb6 vfat     C7C8-2185                            f4acedc8-06                                     

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1               62.6G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2               88.7M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                  2G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1               25.8G   0% /home
/dev/sdb5                1.9G  74% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


====================== sdb5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   f1501797-4928-43d3-a4d5-e8c71a54e4e0
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic   f1501797-4928-43d3-a4d5-e8c71a54e4e0
Windows 10 (on sda1)   E0661E18661DF050
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=f1501797-4928-43d3-a4d5-e8c71a54e4e0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=C7C8-2185  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=a28c5665-adcb-4999-830e-34a72252755e /home           ext4    defaults        0       2

======================= sdb5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sdb5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  33.329273224 = 35.787034624   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  36.428928375 = 39.115264000   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
  35.299800873 = 37.902872576   boot/vmlinuz                                   2
  35.299800873 = 37.902872576   boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic                 2
  35.357879639 = 37.965234176   boot/initrd.img                                2
  35.357879639 = 37.965234176   boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic              2
  35.357879639 = 37.965234176   boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sdb5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 16  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 16  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 16  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 16  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 16  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 16  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 16  2022 41_custom

===================== sdb6/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid f1501797-4928-43d3-a4d5-e8c71a54e4e0 root hd1,msdos5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to remove grub-efi) and reinstall the grub2 of
sdb5 into the MBR of sdb.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because legacy Windows detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB). 

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (ATA 128GB SSD) disk!
The boot of your PC is in UEFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360543/convert-from-efi-to-bios-boot-mode)

Comment: Looks like old BIOS install of Windows and both BIOS & UEFI for Ubuntu. Grub only boots working Windows. And grub must be in same boot mode or BIOS for you. That also means Windows cannot be hibernated. Windows fast start up sets hibernation flag, so you must turn it off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  Since hardware UEFI, better to have installed both systems in UEFI boot mode to gpt drives. But good backups required.

Comment: If Windows is installed in BIOS mode on disk sda and Ubuntu and Grub are installed in UEFI mode on disk sdb you cannot boot Windows from Grub. In order to do that both have to be installed in the same way. Use the bootmenu to boot Windows.