# Ubuntu 22.04.2 installation won't boot from SSD - Lenovo X270

Tags: boot, ssd, lenovo

I GAVE UP ON THIS ... BUT THE QUESTION (AND ANSWERS) MIGHT HELP SOMEONE ELSE IN FUTURE.

I am trying to install the latest Ubuntu (22.04.2) on a Lenovo X270. SSD died so I bought a new one and wanted to give Ubuntu a go. Installed it from a USB boot.

I followed this tutorial video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wc4GjV_Ahb8) about partitioning the hard drive, including creating an EFI partition. I'm trying to install Ubuntu ONLY on the device - not a dual boot with Windows as well.

But after the installation Ubuntu just won't boot from the SSD. I've changed the settings in the BIOS to boot from the SSD, I've allowed it to book from UFEI or Legacy, and I've disabled the secure boot thing.

When it's booting from UFEI it just keeps returning to the Lenovo power-up logo without booting. When booting from Legacy it comes up with a white text error.

I've tried to use the 'boot-repair' program but that gets stuck too. It comes up with the following error message: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr)

I've tried to reset the CMOS and I think I managed to because I had to re-input the time and date in the BIOS, but it's not solved the issue.

Also ... when I try to install grub in the terminal it says "error: cannot find EFI directory". There is definitely an EFI partition.

Any ideas? I've tried my best to look online but I'm not a computer expert and I don't understand most of the instructions people are suggesting with the terminal etc - because they seem to include a lot of assumed knowledge. Any proposed solution needs to be understandable to a noob.

If someone is able to help it would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: may be you have to convert ubuntu to bios mode, see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1203888/1698042 may solve your problem

Comment: Do you have another security setting in UEFI? Some may require you to set an UEFI password, but never lose that or reset to blank when done. Check mount of ESP - efi system partition in /etc/fstab in your install. That needs the UUID of ESP on external drive. For external drive you do need to install grub to external drivem but since you have ESP, it should work. Ubiquity installer still used with some flavors:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Thanks so much! After a couple of weeks struggling with it I gave up last night and just installed Windows 10 - which worked first time. I ended up in the grub BIOS terminal thing and the nightmare was just getting deeper and deeper. Appreciate the attempts to help!